# New class selected by LINQ query, how to transfer to another model?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm really not understanding this as I've only dabbled in MVC and C#. I apologize if my terminology is wrong or confusing, I will do my best to answer questions. I have a couple models like so:

```
 public class DataSharingModels
{
    public string ReferenceID { get; set; }
    public NBTC NBTCGroup { get; set; }
    public Contractors ContractorsGroup { get; set; }
    public Coordinators CoordinatorsGroup { get; set; }
    public NGO NGOGroup { get; set; }
    public Public PublicGroup { get; set; }
    public SelectList FA_RA_List { get; set; }

}

public class NBTC
{
    public String NBTC_FA_Centroid { get; set; }
    public String NBTC_FA_Bound { get; set; }
    public String NBTC_RA_Centroid { get; set; }
    //more properties...
 }
```

The `DataSharingModels` class contains the `public NBTC NBTCGroup` property. It is not `public List<NBTC> NBTCGroup` because there will only be one produced per instance of the controller being hit.

Now in my controller, I have a LINQ statement that selects a new NBTC class:

```
var nbtcVals = (from ds in db.SharingPermissions
                        where ds.FocalRefID.ToString() == ReferenceID
                        && ds.ShareGroup == "NBTC"
                        select new NBTC
                        {
                            NBTC_FA_Centroid = ds.CIP_FA_Centroid,
                            NBTC_FA_Bound = ds.CIP_FA_Boundary,
                            NBTC_RA_Centroid = ds.CIP_RA_Centroid,
                            //more properties...
                        });
```

Where I'm going wrong is I would like to add that to my `DataSharingModels` model. I thought the `nbtcVals` type would be NBTC, but it's IQueryable<##.Models.NBTC>. I understand I could do this, but it seems redundant:

```
        DataSharingModels dsm = new DataSharingModels();

        if (nbtcVals.Any())
        {
            foreach (var i in nbtcVals)
            {
                dsm.NBTCGroup.NBTC_FA_Centroid = i.NBTC_FA_Centroid;
                dsm.NBTCGroup.NBTC_FA_Boundary = i.NBTC_FA_Bound;
                dsm.NBTCGroup.NBTC_RA_Centroid = i.NBTC_RA_Centroid;
                //more properties...
            }
        }
```

What is a more direct way to do this? There must be one. I supposed I could also return an anonymous type in the LINQ query and then assign each property in the `foreach` like `dsm.NBTCGroup.NBTC_RA_Centroid = i.NBTC_RA_Centroid` but that seems the same as the other way.

Comment: NBTCGroup is of type NBTC, not an IQueryable<NBTC> or IEnumerable<NBTC>. You could make that of type IEnumerable<NBTC>. Last code section is meaningless, looping each NBTC and setting the values to the each one of the values in the list and then using the last one (you could simply do nbtcVals.AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault then).

Comment: @Cetin Basoz - `nbtcVals.AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault();` was exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: OK. Note that LastOrDefault is not converted to a SQL, thus it gets the whole data first, and enumerates that locally and gets the last one. On small sets that wouldn't be a problem but is unnecessary to get the whole data and would be slow on large sets. Adding a workaround as an answer.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - since I know that this query will only return one record, would it make more sense to use .SingleOrDefault()?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. But the difference is that, if it returns more than one it raises an exception with SingleOrDefault (no error with FirstOrDefault) - and you don't need OrderByDescending then. IOW SingleOrDefault enforces to return 1 or 0 records and used by primary key searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var nbtcgroup = (from ds in db.SharingPermissions
                        where ds.FocalRefID.ToString() == ReferenceID
                        && ds.ShareGroup == "NBTC"
                        select new NBTC
                        {
                            NBTC_FA_Centroid = ds.CIP_FA_Centroid,
                            NBTC_FA_Bound = ds.CIP_FA_Boundary,
                            NBTC_RA_Centroid = ds.CIP_RA_Centroid,
                            //more properties...
                        })
              .OrderByDescending(n => n.Id) // or some other property that could identify sorting
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

This one has a translation to SQL (LIMIT or TOP depending on backend).